# Odoo attribute name domain can't link

Tags: xml, odoo

```
<attribute name="domain">[ ('company_id', 'in', [False, company_id]) ]</attribute>
```

`company_id` in `analytic_account_id` makes this code can't work.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKDIg.png)

How to fix it?

I think I should write something can make `analytic_account_id` link `company_id`.

I tried to write

```
<attribute name="domain">[ ('company_id', 'in', [False, analytic_account_id/company_id]) ]</attribute>
```

or

```
 <attribute name="domain">[ ('company_id','in',[False, analytic_account_id,'in, [False, company_id]) ]</attribute>
```

and

```
<attribute name="domain" domain="[('company_id', 'in', [False, parent.analytic_account_id.company_id])]"/>
```

but it still didn't work.

Comment: The `company_id` field must be present in the view where you add the field domain

Answer (score 0):

Your domain requires the field `company_id` to be present in the view you are using that specific domain.

Try adding this field into the view, and it should work.

```
<field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
```